# How do I execute code upon session timeout?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I'd like to clear up some temporary data when a user's `Session` expires on my website. While most data is stored in the session object itself, there are some external locks and reservations I'd like to release alongside the session.

Where do I put the code to do this?

Comment: what kind of locks and reservations?

Comment: On tickets or seats, for instance. But that has nothing to do with the question. I just want to know how I can execute an arbitrary block of code when a user's session times out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [inProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatemode.aspx) then you can do this add the [following](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatemodule.end.aspx) in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Session_End");
}
```

Otherwise you might think of a different approach, that is making the reservations themselves truly temporary, having a timeout on those reservations themselves that matches the session, which could be extended along with the users' session.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.